# What is this white stuff in my black bean bag?

Tags: beans

What is this white stuff in my black bean bags?

[image: what is this white stuff in my black bean bags?]

Answer (score 6):

Those are clearly some kind of insect eggs.  Double-bag the beans and dispose of them as soon as you can.